# What happens if I overwrite my Windows partition with another version of Ubuntu?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, 22.04, toshiba-satellite

On my laptop, I have both Windows 10 (although it came with Windows 8.1 prepackaged) and Ubuntu 18.04. It is really old (Toshiba Satellite C50D A) and it can barely run Windows 10 while Ubuntu runs without problems - just some slowdowns every now and then.

I wanted to test Ubuntu 22.04 Mate on my Windows partition. When I tried to install it this morning, I had a doubt: will there be any trouble if I overwrite it?

Also, do I need this boot/efi partition?

[image]

Thank you in advance for your help! :-)

Comment: There is no need to install Ubuntu-Mate 22.04 just to test it. Rather, run it from USB. The efi partition is needed, but nothing will explode, burn or tumble down if Windows is overwritten.

Comment: You can run dual boot with different Ubuntu versions and you can also have more than two operating systems (like three or four) if you have enough disk space.

Comment: If you have important files on your Windows partition copy them to the EXT 4 partition ( in live environment/try Ubuntu ). That way you don't have to worry that you loose your data. Then you can install Ubuntu on that partition ( format the partition during setup ).